# Trying to write DRY Scala code with type parameters

Tags: scala, inheritance, case-class, traits, type-parameter

I've defined some case classes that all have a field id: Id[T], where T is the type of the case class. I would like to have a trait enforcing this property to write generic code on these classes.

My first try uses a type parameter and a self type on a trait to enforce this property:

```
case class Id[M](value: Long)

trait EnforceIdType[T] {
  this: T =>
  val id: Id[T]
}

case class A(id: Id[A]) extends EnforceIdType[A]
case class B(id: Id[B]) extends EnforceIdType[B]
// case class C(id: Id[B]) extends EnforceIdType[B] < Won't compile, as expected
```

This is fine but I wonder if there is a way to do the same without using a type parameter on the trait. Here is my second try:

```
case class Id[M](value: Long)

trait EnforceIdType {
  val id: Id[_ <: EnforceIdType]
}

case class A(id: Id[A]) extends EnforceIdType
case class B(id: Id[B]) extends EnforceIdType
case class C(id: Id[B]) extends EnforceIdType // Compiles :(
```

Concretely, I would like to use these definitions of case classes (without passing the type parameter to EnforceIdType) but still enforce the property (this C should not compile). Is there any way to do this? I feel like something like `this.type` could be used here but I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: Why do you get compilation error on C? The above code compiles successfully

Comment: I get a `error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type C does not conform to EnforceIdType[B]'s selftype EnforceIdType[B] with B
       case class C(id: Id[B]) extends EnforceIdType[B]` with the first code snippet on 2.10.2 (which is the expected result).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, `this.type` need to be used, but with some limitation:

```
trait EnforceIdType {
  def id: Id[_ >: this.type <: EnforceIdType]
}

case class A(id: Id[A]) extends EnforceIdType
case class B(id: Id[B]) extends EnforceIdType
//case class C(id: Id[B]) extends EnforceIdType // Won't compile, as expected
```

**Updated:**

About second limitation (shown by Alexey Romanov). It can be eliminated but with long way:

```
//Embeded polymorphism used
class Id(val value: Long) {
  type M
}

// Factory method for shift type variable to type parameter field
object Id {
  def apply[T](value : Long) = new Id(value) { type M = T }
}

trait EnforceIdType {
  type This = this.type // store this.type for use inside Id { type M = .. }
  val id: Id { type M >: This <: EnforceIdType } // need to be val

  def show(x : id.M) { println (x) } // dependent method
}

case class A(id: Id { type M = A }) extends EnforceIdType
case class B(id: Id { type M = B }) extends EnforceIdType
//  case class C(id: Id { type M = B }) extends EnforceIdType // Won't compile, as expected

val a = A( Id[A](10))
val b = B( Id[B](10))

a.show(a)
// a.show(b) // Won't compile, as expected
```

Comment: Some limitations to be aware of: 1. `case class C(id: Id[EnforceIdType]) extends EnforceIdType` will; 2. You won't have problems when writing functions which take/return concrete subtypes, but will if you try to write a function which works with any subtype. Otherwise, very nice trick!

Comment: Thank you, @Alexey Romanov. I have added some workaround (in my answer) for second limitation.

Comment: Another question, why is the `this.type <: EnforceIdType` / `This <: EnforceIdType` part needed? It seems to work fine without it.

Comment: You are right it is work but I try to eliminate first limitation shown by @Alexey Romanov. If you will use `this.type <: EnforceIdType / This <: EnforceIdType`  whithout **Upper Bound** than next code will work `case class C(id: Id[Any]) extends EnforceIdType`